# Record video in 16:9 aspect ratio on the iPad running iOS 11

Tags: ipad, video, video-capture

How can I record a video on iOS with an aspect radio of 16:9? I am using the iPad 9.7" 2017 model. I am running iOS 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant. You need an external editor to convert it to 16:9.  I think it is very short sighted of Apple by not having this ability in iOS.

Answer (score 2):

Double tap on the screen while the camera is in video mode. That will switch the aspect ratio between 4:3 and 16:9.

> I was fooling around with my iPad 2 and I found that you can change the aspect ratio when taking video! (not sure if this works on other iOS devices running iOS 4.3) But all you have to do is go to your iPad 2’s camera app, and double tap on the view finder. (I double tapped on the right side of the screen).
>
> That’s it! Now you can record widescreen (16:9 ratio) 720p video instead of the regular “legacy” full screen (4:3 ratio) 720p video!

[Source](http://leimobile.com/how-to-change-the-aspect-ratio-of-ipad-2-video-recordings/)